# Finding $P$ if $P(\{n\})$ proportional to $(1/6)^n$ for all $n\in \Omega$

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega,P)$ be a probability space with $\Omega=\{0,1,2,..\}$.

> Find $P$ if $P(\{n\})$ proportional to $(1/6)^n$ for all $n\in \Omega$

**My attempt:**

$P(\{n\})=\beta \frac1 {6^n}$

$1=P(\Omega)=\sum\limits_{n\in \Omega} P(\{n\})$

> How can I procced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$\sum\limits_{n\in \Omega} \beta \frac1 {6^n} = 1$

Pull through the $\beta$ to get $\beta\sum\limits_{n\in \Omega}  \frac1 {6^n} = 1$

Now the set $\Omega$ is the natural numbers so you have

$\beta\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac1 {6^n} = 1$

That sum is the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with $r=\frac16$ which is equal to $\frac 1{1-\frac 16}$

So $\beta = 1-\frac 16$

Comment: מעולה תודה רבה לך

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped.